# Undefined variable after upgrade to Vite version 4.3.0

Tags: sass, vite, scss-mixins

After I upgraded to Vite 4.3.0 I get "undefined variable" error. I am trying to import variables, mixins etc. from a design system, which worked perfectly fine with Vite 4.2.2. When I updated however, I get "[sass] Undefined variable". The import in itself is working, as it has no trouble finding the file. This only happens with Vite 4.3.0 and newer versions. Also, in my _mixins.scss file, it struggles to find functions in the same file (shown in image below).

I have found some similar questions, but none of the answers have helped. Among other things, I have tried to add preprocessorOptions in the vite.config.js file, exchange @import with @use and upgrade other dependencies. I tried to dive into the changelog for Vite 4.3.0, but did not get any smarter.

The dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "classnames": "^2.3.2",
  "date-fns": "^2.30.0",
  "react": "^18.2.0",
  "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^6.11.1",
  "react-use": "^17.4.0",
  "sass": "^1.62.1",
  "typescript": "^5.0.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@types/react": "^18.2.6",
  "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.4",
  "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.0",
  "vite": "^4.3.0",
  "vite-plugin-svgr": "^3.2.0"
},
```

As I said before, this works perfectly fine until I upgrade Vite from 4.2.2 to 4.3.0. Does anyone know what the issue can be?

The _variables.scss file:

[image: In _variables.scss]

The error:

[image: The error]

The _mixings.scss file:

[image: the _mixings.scss file]

The _tokens.scss file in the design system which I am trying to import from

[image: The _tokens.scss file in the design system which I am trying to import from]

Comment: do `@use '/filepath/tokens' as *` or `@use 'filepath/tokens as tokens*` (you can use any name on the place of tokens) and if you are using the second method than your code will be like this `$color--text: tokens.color-alias-dark-gray`. See this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CR-a8upNjJ0) to learn more.

Comment: Yes, I already tried that but it does not solve the errors in the third image (mixins). E.g., tokens.$spacing does not work since it is a parameter passed in the function. But it still says that it can't find the variables and functions in that file.

Comment: I didn't quite get what your function is doing !!

Comment: I have tried what you suggested, now using: @use 'filepath/tokens as tokens' and $color--text: tokens.$color-alias-dark-gray. This removes the yellow underlines in the editor, but it still says [plugin:vite:css] [sass] Undefined Variable.